# DcDiag: "Warning: The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was not found (probably a misconfiguration)" meaning?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller

Does this mean there is no Forward Lookup Zone by the name of the domain (say domain.local) in DNS? 
I only have the log of dcdiag, not the actual machine, so I cannot check.

Later it says:

> Matching A record found at DNS server %own IP%:
>                    dc2.domain.local

So dcdiag says there is a record in a zone that is not there? Or does dcdiag not notice when a record is found using a forwarder?

**UPDATE:** The DNS server has two DNS servers configured as forwarders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: changed answer, because partly it was nonsense and partly it didn't apply.

Possibly the server has only a stub zone, which can include A records. The AD zone includes also structures like "_msdcs", "_sites", "_tcp", "_udp", "domaindnszones" and "forestdnszones", which are necessary to find the directory services in the AD.

Also the A record could be served by the forwarders.

EDIT: When you have access to the server, check for the zone being primary, and having the above mentioned SRV entries.

You can read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(WS.10).aspx) in more detail than I'm able to explain how DNS is used for AD, an whats needed.

Comment: The NIC has only itself (127.0.0.1) configured as DNS server. What do you mean by:"When DcDiag searches for the zone, it does so possibly not by querying for a name."?

Comment: OK to make sure I got this right. You say that dcdiag might report that the "Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was not found" because it is missing the specific subfolders, but the zone exists as a stub with A host record for the DC?

Comment: a stub zone is a type of zone in MS DNS, which is not authoritative. I only suspect thats the case with your server, I don't really know. I also don't know whether these folders _have_ to be absent, but they aren't usually there in a stub zone.